# How to select all attributes of certain children via single XPath expression?

Tags: xml, matlab, xpath, attributes

My XML format is as below

```
<node id="7463888842" lat="6666" lon="66666" version="6">
    <tag k="power" v="substation"/>
    <tag k="voltage" v="20000"/>
    <tag k="building" v="transformer_tower"/>
    <tag k="substation" v="minor_distribution"/>
</node>
<node id="277852742" lat="6766" lon="666676" version="6">
    <tag k="ref" v="64268"/>
    <tag k="name" v="Hambergen Sandstraße"/>
    <tag k="power" v="substation"/>
    <tag k="voltage" v="20000"/>
    <tag k="location" v="kiosk"/>
    <tag k="operator" v="EWE"/>
    <tag k="frequency" v="50"/>
    <tag k="substation" v="minor_distribution"/>
</node>
<node id="274965842" lat="66" lon="666" version="6"/>
<node id="2732132642" lat="666" lon="6666" version="6"/>
<node id="274454552" lat="6" lon="6.6" version="6"">
    <tag k="power" v="substation"/>
</node>
```

I only need those nodes which have attributes `k="power" v="substation"` and if this is a match I need all the other attributes (ie. both `k="_something_" and v="_something_"` in the same node.

For the first part (to find out all nodes with `k="power" v="substation"`, I have used this XPath expression

```
expression1sub = xpath.compile('self::*[tag[@v="station"] or tag[@v= "substation"] or tag[@v="sub_station"]]');
```

and checked using this

```
List = expression1sub.evaluate(nodes.item(i), XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
```

Now I check if `List` is true and if it is true I need all the other attributes in all tags.

For example: for first node since tag `k="power" v="substation"`is present i need all other attributes (ie. `voltage 20000, building, transformer_tower, substation, minor_distribution`).

Please let me know if I can achieve this using a single XPath expression in MATLAB.

I tried using this XPath

```
self::*[tag[@v="station"] or tag[@v= "substation"] or tag[@v="sub_station"]]/tag[@*]
```

but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath will select all attribute values for the `tag` elements beneath a `node` containing a `tag` element that has both `@k='power'` and `@k='substation'`:

```
//node[tag[@k='power' and @v='substation']]/tag/@*
```

For your sample XML, this returns:

```
power
substation
voltage
20000
building
transformer_tower
substation
minor_distribution
ref
64268
name
Hambergen Sandstraße
power
substation
voltage
20000
location
kiosk
operator
EWE
frequency
50
substation
minor_distribution
power
substation
```

Or, if you want to exclude the `tag` with `@k='power'` and `@k='substation'`:

```
//node[tag[@k='power' and @v='substation']]/tag[not(@k='power' and @v='substation')]/@*
```

For your sample XML, this returns:

```
voltage
20000
building
transformer_tower
substation
minor_distribution
ref
64268
name
Hambergen Sandstraße
voltage
20000
location
kiosk
operator
EWE
frequency
50
substation
minor_distribution
```

Note that both XPath expressions (any XPath expression really) assume a single root element to your XML.